# ¿Cómo hacer un simple cálculo que da un resultado de matriz de tamaño 1*1?

Tags: python, matemáticas, ipython

He hecho un cálculo entre dos vectores de tamaño `(m,n)` y `(n,m)` para obtener un solo valor en Python. Sin embargo no soy capaz de realizar este simple cálculo para que dé este resultado. Entonces:

**¿Cómo hacer un simple cálculo que da un resultado de matriz de tamano 1*1 con python en ipython?**

Por ejemplo:

```
In[1]:x = np.array([2,-1,1])
In[2]:w = np.array([1,-0.5,0])
In[3]:y = np.dot(xT,w)+b
In[4]:print y
```

Que da:

```
[ 3.]
```

Después quiero usar este resultado para hacer este cálculo:

```
In[5]:e =1/2(y-1)^2
```

Pero obtengo un error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-deee1f67656a> in <module>()
----> 1 error =1/2(y-1)^2

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas cometiendo un error de sintaxis, te falta el operador de multiplicación (`*`) en `1/2(y-1)`. Cuando el intérprete llega a un paréntesis precedido de un entero sin un simbolo matemático entre ambos interpreta que es una llamada a función, lógicamente un entero no es una función por lo que el error es claro:

> 'int' object is not callable

Por otro lado, el símbolo de potenciación en  Python es `**`. El operador `^` es un [xor a nivel de bit](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disyunci%C3%B3n_exclusiva). Tal y como lo tienes te tirará otro error del tipo:

> TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_xor' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''.

La línea, debería quedar así:

```
e =1/2*(y-1)**2
```

Lo que nos da :

```
[ 2.]
```